# Jquery IF maybe?

Tags: jquery

I use the following code to find a particular table, hide it then show it on click:

```
$(function() {
  $('.Nav table .navitem').hide();
  $('.Nav table.navheader').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().next().find(".navitem").slideToggle('100');
  });
});
```

Here is the HTML Output:

```
<div class="Nav">

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table class="navheader" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
       <tr>
        <td style="width:100%;"><a navheader" href="#">Header</a></td>
       </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="navSubMenu">
       <tr>
        <td>
         <table class="ms-navitem" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
          <tr>
           <td style="width:100%;"><a class=" ms-navitem" href="#" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">Item</a></td>
          </tr>
         </table>
        </td>
       </tr>
      </table>
```

A basic accordion navigation hacked together from a table, however some of the .havheader's do not have .navitem's so I dont want these to be clickable.

How best can i achieve this?

Comment: As a side note, 3 levels of table nesting just to create some navigation links seems to be overkill.  You should be able to create the same effect using an Unordered List (UL).

Comment: I agree except the HTML is 'pre-generated' and editing that opens up a whole new can of worms. I have to work with what I've got.

Comment: Is table class ="ms-navitem" is that supposed to be "navitem".
And <a navheader> is that supposed to be <a class="navheader"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this selector:

```
$('.Nav table.navheader')
```

to this:

```
$('.Nav table.navheader:has(.navitem)')
```

Comment: I've change my post to show HTML out put as your suggestion does not work, but seems to come very close.

Comment: This doesnt work because .navitem is outside of .navheader so the table.navheader does not have an element of .navitem.

.navitem is a table outside.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want accordion, maybe it is better to use jQuery UI instead...

Comment: I would if that were possible however the HTML cannot be altered, see comments above in original post.